# GraphQL like Gatsby in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, graphql, gatsby

the question i have is is there a way to get Graphql setup in Next.js like in Gatsby.
so that i can query the pages and get the data from it.
Are there plugins for Next.js like the Gatsby-file-source and gatsby-markdown-remark etc.
For example:

```
`export const query = graphql`
     query($slug: String!) {
      mdx(frontmatter: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
       frontmatter {
        tags
        slug
        title
        date
        country
        categories
        }
       }
      }`
```

with that i can query all the mdx files that i have in the project and get the frontmatter from it to use and store.

From what i found Gatsby somehow transform the files into nodes that graphql can read and query

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Graphql nodes, but you can convert your mdx into json.
Try **[ContentLayer](https://contentlayer.dev/docs)** with Mdx plugins for that.

Thereafter, you can map that json to resolve it from Graphql or directly import the json data. AFAIK, contentlayer along with Mdx should be enough. [Details](https://contentlayer.dev/docs/sources/files/mdx-d747e46d)

Additionally, adding [remark-code-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/remark-code-import) as a plugin might help in importing the code from a file.